# Symfony2 - encoding url parameters like slash, dot and plus

Tags: symfony, routes, special-characters, urlencode

Ich have a problem with symfony2(2.0.16) routing.

I try to run 2 routes like

```
route1:
  host/my/route/{param}
    requirements: 
      param: ".*[^/]$"
route2:
  host/my/route/category/{param}
    requirements: 
      param: ".*[^/]$"
```

As you can imagine, the second route will not be called, not matter what..

what i actually want to do is a search and a specialized search, therefore i need to allow also dots, plus and slashes..

I tried to encode the slash (urlencode to  %2F or %252F) so that i can change the requirement, but symfony always decodes it before the routing, so i get an routing error if i remove the requirement.

I thought about to use base64 encoding, but that cant be the solution to my problem..

EDIT: i can also not rely on the order of the routes, because i import the routes from many diffrent bundles..

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html

Comment: Also you might need to swap the routes, because routes are tested from top to bottom. As the second one is more specific, but it above the less specific one (compare with note *"Earlier Routes always Win"*). Please make yourself comfortable with the general workings of Symfony2 routes: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/routing.html

Comment: thx for the answers, but how i mentioned in the post i can _not_ rely on the order of the routes, i am well aware of the basic routing workflow and i read the cookbook

if i use the requirement to allow slash for the param, it will "eat" the route, as it is up there in my example (my pattern just looks diffrent, because i dont like slashes at the end)

Answer (score 1):

```
#This one before the other to be considered !
route2:
  host/my/route/category/{param}
    requirements: 
      param: ".+"

route1:
  host/my/route/{param}
    requirements: 
      param: ".+"
```

Comment: i am sorry, but i cant rely on the order of the routes, in the project i am working we just have to much routes and import them from diffrent bundles, we have to ensure that the routes are unique

Comment: Ensure that they are unique, ok, but you'll have to manage and rely on the order as the routing component searches for the first pattern matching the request's URL.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter for your first route can't be `category` else it will match it instead of ignoring it. You can change the regex to ignore this value:

```
route1:
  host/my/route/{param}
    requirements: 
      param: "(?!category/).*[^/]$"
route2:
  host/my/route/category/{param}
    requirements: 
      param: ".*[^/]$"
```

Now a parameter called `category` followed by a slash will be ignored and the pattern won't match, except by the second route.